# how to fill a list with 0 using python 

Tags: python, list

I want to get a fixed length list from another list like:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
b = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

And I want to get a list like this: `['a','b','c',0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`. In other words, if `len(a) < len(b)`, i want to fill up list `a` with values from list `b` up to length of the list `b`, somewhat similar to what [`str.ljust`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=ljust#str.ljust) does.

This is my code:

```
a=['a','b','c']
b = [0 for i in range(5)]
b = [a[i] for i in b if a[i] else i]

print a
```

But it shows error:

```
  File "c.py", line 7
    b = [a[i] for i in b if a[i] else i]
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What can i do?

Comment: >>> b = [0 for i in range(10)]
>>> a=['a','b','c']
>>> b = [0 for i in range(10)]
>>> c = [a[i] if i < len(a) else b[i] for i in xrange(len(b)) ]
>>> c
['a', 'b', 'c', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Why not just:

```
a = a + [0]*(maxLen - len(a))
```

Comment: This works well for immutable objects (like `0`) but won't work for mutable objects.  `[0 for i in range(maxlen-len(a)]` works for both immutable and mutable objects.

Comment: As the original poster asked for zeros, that should not be a problem. And you example works only for mutable objects, if you make sure that you create a new one for each i. I you just replace the 0 with another variable, you will have the same problem.

Comment: @S.Lott 's answer seems to work just fine for mutable objects for me.

Answer (score 30):

Use itertools repeat.

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> a + list(repeat(0, 6))
['a', 'b', 'c', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Will not work with mutable objects. Try `lst = list(repeat([0], 10))`, then `lst[0][0] = 1` and then print `lst`.

Comment: @naktinis Easily adaptable (moreso than the top answer) with a list comprehension: `a + [MyMutable() for repeat(0, 6)]`.

Answer (score 9):

Why not just

```
c = (a + b)[:len(b)]
```

Answer (score 4):

To be more explicit, this solution replaces the first elements of `b` with all of the elements of `a` regardless of the values in `a` or `b`:

```
a + b[len(a):]
```

This will also work with:

```
>>> a = ['a', ['b'], None, False]
>>> b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a + b[len(a):]
['a', ['b'], None, False, 4, 5]
```

If you do not want to the result to be longer than `b`:

```
>>> a = ['a', ['b'], None, False]
>>> b = [0, 1, 2]
>>> (a + b[len(a):])[:len(b)]
['a', ['b'], None]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
LIST_LENGTH = 10
a = ['a','b','c']

while len(a) < LIST_LENGTH:
    a.append(0)
```

Comment: This is so simple and explicit. There was no list comprehension-fu or slice-notation-fu to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

```
a+[0]*(len(b) - len(a))

['a', 'b', 'c', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fill with mutable values, for example with `dict`s:

```
map(lambda x: {}, [None] * n)
```

Where `n` is the number of elements in the array.

```
>>> map(lambda x: {}, [None] * 14)
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
>>> l = map(lambda x: {}, [None] * 14)
>>> l[0]
{}
>>> l[0]['bar'] = 'foo'
>>> l
[{'bar': 'foo'}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

Populating without the `lambda` would cause every element to be `{'bar': 'foo'}`!

Comment: `[{} for x in range(14)]` achieves the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
maxlen = 10
result = [(0 if i+1 > len(a) else a[i])  for i in range(maxlen)]
```

I like some of the other solutions better.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
a.extend(b[len(a):])
# a is now ['a', 'b', 'c', 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just do:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
b = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

c = a + b #= ['a','b','c',0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: Having a fixed length is no problem for concatenating lists.

Comment: The result for your example should be `['a', 'b', 'c', 0, 0, 0, 0]` in order to match the OP's requirement.